# Is there a LOAD or STORE in Legv8 that uses another register instead of a immediate offset?

Tags: assembly, cpu-architecture, arm64

Is there a load or store instruction in Legv8 that does not use a immediate offset? i do not have a value for i in the bottom question and i cant offset for data[i] when i use LDUR or STUR. I used STR and LDR from ARMv8. Is there another way i could have answered this question?

> Convert the following C program into LEGv8 assembly program. Assume variables k, x, y and i are associated with registers X19, X20, X21, and X22 respectively. The base address of array data[] is in register X25. Each element of array data[] occupies 8 bytes.

```
if ( x > y )  
     k = x – y;  
else  
    k = y – x;  
while (data[i] < k) {  
    data[i] = data[i] + k;  
    i = i + 1;
```

This is what i wrote.

```
IF:  
    SUBS X23, X20, X21 // CHECK IF X> Y  
B.LT ELSE // IF LESS THAN, BRANCH TO ELSE  
    SUB X19, X20, X21 // STORE K = X-Y  
B.LOOP  
ELSE:   
    SUB X19, X21, X20 // STORE K= Y-X;  
LOOP:  
    LDR X24, [X25, X22] // load into X24, base address from X24 with offset from X22  
    SUBS X18, X24, X19 // CHECK IF data[i] < k  
    B.GT EXIT  
    ADD X24, X24, X19 // data[i] += k  
STR X24, [X25, X22] // store into X25 with offset from X22, the value from X24  
    ADDI X22, X22, #1 // I += 1  
    B.LOOP  
EXIT:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`str`/`ldr` are the normal instructions that can use a variety of addressing modes.

`ldur`/`stur` are only useful with register + constant offset when the immediate constant isn't a multiple of 4 or 8.

The normal form of `ldr` with that addressing mode encodes it as a scaled value so it can use a wider range of offsets.  The U means "unscaled".  (But that's an *encoding* detail: the asm source code still always has a byte offset like `ldr w0, [x0, 4]` to load the next `int` after the one pointed to by `x0`.  [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/Bd5UsA)).  But as I said, `ldr`/`str` can use any addressing mode.

You're correct that `ldur` is useless for `data[i]` with runtime-variable `i`.

> Is there another way i could have answered this question?

Yes, of course there are many ways to arrange your loop.  e.g. use a pointer increment instead of a 2-register addressing mode, calculating `data+i` outside the loop.

Or incrementing your counter by 8 as a byte offset instead of an array index you need to scale every time you use it.  (I think you forgot this unless LEGv8 is different from AArch64).

Or optimize away `i` and just calculate an end-pointer to compare against.

Or even vectorizing with AdvSIMD (AArch64 version of NEON) SIMD instructions to do 2 adds at once.

Also you could structure the loop with the conditional branch at the bottom which is always good (fewer instructions inside the loop).  Even if it means you need a compare/branch to maybe skip the loop if it should run zero times.

But all these ways just use `ldr`/`str`, not `ldur`/`stur`.  You have no need for an offset as part of the addressing mode, just 2 registers.

Comment: there is no i value given. in this case which approach should i take to factor this into consideration?

Comment: Also i checked an ARMv8 manual which said that STR and LDR is able to take in registers

Comment: @TanYuHauSean: Yes, STR/LDR are the normal instructions that can use a variety of addressing modes.  LDUR/STUR are only useful with register + constant offset when the constant isn't a multiple of 4 or 8.  That's what I was trying to say in my answer.

Comment: if i were to use  
LSL X11, X22, #8 // X11 = I*8  
ADD X12, X25, X11 // X12 = data[i]  
would this work?

Comment: @TanYuHauSean huh?  No, that's not a load.  If it's supposed to be a pointer calculation, it also doesn't match the comments.  LSL by 8 is a left-shift by 8, aka multiply by 256.  log2(8) = 3 so you only need to shift by 3.  Like [`ldr     x0, [x0, x1, lsl 3]`](https://godbolt.org/z/Em-NGp) to implement `data[i]` where `data` is a 64-bit pointer type.  Writing a simple C function is an easy way to get the compiler to show you the right syntax for the scaled-index addressing mode you want.

Comment: my bad. I mistyped the #3. i was thinking of multiplying it by 8.

Comment: but if done in that way, i can calculate the pointer of data[i], is that right?

Comment: @TanYuHauSean: you could inefficiently use 2 separate instruction (LSL and ADD) before a single-register LDR, yes.  IDK why you'd do that instead of a scaled-index LDR, though, if you don't want to just optimize away the `i` variable like a C compiler might (e.g. increment a register by 8 so you can use `ldr reg, [reg, reg]`).  You could at least use ADD with a left-shifted source operand, like `add x12, x25, x22, lsl #3` unless LEGv8 disallows that.

Comment: I think i could do that method, but as it is not what my lecturer has shown during his lectures i m worried that i may get marks deducted for using something i am unfamiliar with. Thank you for your advice regarding the topic though.